# How to style a video to take fit an entire div, keep aspect ratio and be responsive as the page shrinks?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

Im trying to do this exact thing https://www.javycoffee.com/

Comment: Set `width: 100%` to the `<video />` tag

Comment: You can't of course have the whole video showing on all viewports as their aspect ratios will be different from the videos. You can use object-fit: cover which will crop the video either top and bottom or at the sides as required.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution that gets me closest to my result. I put the video on its own page. Made it the page background image and then scaled it.

Keep it on its own page, dont use container and use max-height to scale it.

CSS

```
const StyledVideo = styled.video`
    filter: saturate(1.1) contrast(0.7) opacity(0.79) brightness(0.9);
    object-fit: cover;
    width: 100% !important;
    max-height: 600px !important;

`;


function Video() {
    return (
            <StyledVideo autoPlay muted loop id="myVideo">
                <source src={} type="video/mp4" />
            </StyledVideo>
    );
}

export default Video;
```